# How can I find the superclass of a Function Object in Python?

Tags: python, function, class

So if I code:

```
a=False
print(type(a))
print(bool.mro())
```

The result is:

```
<class 'bool'>
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'object'>]
```

What works perfectly well in my point of view, although, if I run the following code I get an error:

```
def F():
  pass
print(type(F))
print(function.mro())
```

The error:

```
<class 'function'>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

how is " function" not defined since it says that is a class?

Comment: `function` is not a name in either the global scope nor builtins. Why do you think it *has* to be in either of those? Just use `type(F)`, so `type(F).mro()`

Comment: It worked the way you said, Thank you! I thought that because print points for a class "function", the name "function" was a builtin.

Comment: `<class 'function'>` is defined in `types` module. Try `types.FunctionType`

Comment: @warownia1 it's not, actually defined there. If you look at the source, it is simply  something like `FunctionType = type(lambda : None)` The type is defined as part of the CPython runtime. It is *exposed* in the `types` module. Not all types that exist are exposed in the built-in namespace

Comment: True, so it's more like the function type is an internal python magic. Nonetheless, it's available in the typing module.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, could you send some source about this topic? Im not finding it easily by myself

Answer (score 0):

Your first lines of code work because `bool` is a [builtin function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool)
This is not the case for `function`